# text align in label error?

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jlabel, layout-manager

at now i am trying to add a label beside a frame. And i have a text for the label and want to align it to center but it fails and always be left-align. Please help me!

```
Simulation sm = new Simulation(dm);
JFrame simulation = new JFrame();
simulation.setTitle("Traffic light and Car park Siumulation");

simulation.setSize(800,600);
simulation.setResizable(false);
simulation.setVisible(true);
simulation.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
simulation.add(sm, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//Carpark label
JLabel carparklb = new JLabel("abcd");
carparklb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,600));

carparklb.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
carparklb.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);

simulation.add(carparklb, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Java Docs

> setVerticalTextPosition(int textPosition)
>
> Sets the vertical position of the label's text, **relative to its image**.

Try [JLabel.setVerticalAlignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setVerticalAlignment%28int%29) and [JLabel.setHorizontalAlignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setHorizontalAlignment%28int%29) instead

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`carparklb.setAlignmentY(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);`
`carparklb.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);`

This will align the text to the center of the label both horizontally and vertically. If you only wanted to center it horizontally, you can try either:

`JLabel carparklb = new JLabel("abcd", JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);`

or

`carparklb.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);`

Answer (score 1):

Use html code as:

```
    "<html><font size=\"5\"><P ALIGN =\"CENTER\">ARGHYA</P></font></html>"
```

and use it as the String in the label.